# How to frequently get data from an api?

Tags: android, api

I am working on a football scores application. How am I supposed to manage the live scores?
We have our own api, which is getting the data from a paid api. I know one method is to constantly hit the api after, let's say every 5 seconds, but is that the correct method? Or is there any other way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: its a workaround implement silent push notification .Ask your server side to send silent push notification to your app whenever there is an update in live score and handle your api calls according to notification else i will suggest you to use websocket .

Comment: Any link from where I can get started?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for this type of functionality.
The first is to query the server every X seconds for fresh data (like you described)
The method I like better is using web sockets or other form of bi directional communication with the server that push the client the changes every time fresh data arrives from the 3rd party API or on some other logic you decide.

Comment: I know about sockets.io. What other bi-directional communication option do I have?

Comment: some other options: Long Polling, Multiplexing, HTTP/2 Server Push. I believe there are more, these are the things i worked with.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the Realtime database for the live score app. Websocket can send the data constantly and you don't need to call API every 5 seconds. Follow [This Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) to know about the Realtime Database. When there is any update in your database then the app will auto-refresh the data and show you the current score in your app.

Constantly hitting the API is not a good practice, this can hang your mobile.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am looking for other options.
We currently have a SQL database. And we don't intend on using firebase's database due to their pricing.

Comment: brother uses WebSockets to get a realtime response there is no other option to run your app in realtime.

Comment: Any link to get started from?

Comment: your backend team creates sockets and you have to implement in your code.